# Как устранить ошибку в разметке xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

Запускаю проект в студии, и обнаруживается ошибка, ранее все было нормально, а сегодня какой то глюк, почему то слетели все неймспейсы для xaml.

Ошибка      свойство "EventName" не существует в пространстве имен XML "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation". Строка 36 позиция 47.   wpf[arcer   C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\wpf[arcer\wpf[arcer\View\MainWindow.xaml    36

Ошибка  XDG0048 Указанное значение нельзя присвоить коллекции. Требуется следующий тип: "TriggerBase".  wpf[arcer   MainWindow.xaml 36

На стеке кое что прочитал, и добавлял ссылки, перестраивал решение, но увы ошибки не уходят.

Вот разметка.

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_arcer.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:customObjects="clr-namespace:wpf_arcer.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772">
            <TabItem Name="Parse" Header="Парсинг">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,-5,0,5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="672*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="351" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="725" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                    <Label Content="Список категорий" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="27,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button Command="{Binding CommandToRun}" Content="Получить список категорий" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="28,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <Label Content="Глубина парсинга" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="318,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106"/>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="437,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NumberPages, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67"/>
                    <Button  Command="{Binding CommandToPars}" Content="Парсить выбранные страницы" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="536,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="199" RenderTransformOrigin="0.9,0.67"/>
                    <customObjects:CustomListBox x:Name="ListBox"  SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Rubrikses, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedPlanshets, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0,47,449,55" ></customObjects:CustomListBox>
                   </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="Data" Header="Данные">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="361" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="722">

                        <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="31,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="648"  >


                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenWindow}" CommandParameter=""/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        </DataGrid>

                        <Button Command="{Binding CommandGetDataFromBase}" Content="Получить данные из базы" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="227,301,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249"/>
                        <Label Content="Поиск  в базе" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="31,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="134,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="545"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>


        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Потому что надо писать `i:EventTrigger` (потеряли пространство имен)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо за ответ, но ставлю ошибок еще больше становиться, в моем случае в какое место поставить нужно?

Comment: Поправьте пространство имен еще: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Comment: Ну у вас `EventTrigger` только в одном месте, вот там и надо префикс `i:` добавить

Comment: У вас вообще сборка `System.Windows.Interactivity` подключена к проекту?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо заработало все

Comment: @АндрейNOP в этом System.Windows.Interactivity и была проблема.Только написана у меня она была по другому